# how to show a popup menu in the center of a screen

Tags: android

I'm currently using this code;

```
            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, txt_selectPicture,Gravity.CENTER);
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_createpassword, popup.getMenu());
            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Opening : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });

            popup.show(); //showing popup menu
```

here txt_selectPicture is a TextView with gravity center. and this menu is shown on the leftmost side of a screen when this txt_selectPicture is clicked. but i want it to be shown in center. I got this solution

```
            new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, txt_selectPicture,Gravity.CENTER);
```

but it is not working for me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Consider using an AlertDialog. It will by default show up in the middle of the screen regardless of the position of your TextView.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia it work perfectly fine with no errors but as i mentioned above this popup menu instead of showing in center always popup at left side of screen

Comment: @Endor thanks for an alternate it really work. but my app needs a popup menu.

Comment: but your approach fulfil my wants, thanks! question upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_createpassword);
```

instead of

```
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_createpassword, popup.getMenu());
```

Sorry my bad English.